# Different hover link colors for bold text and regular text

Tags: html, css

I know this is a Dumb Question, but how do you set different hover link colors for bold and regular text.

```css
a:hover { color:#cccccc; }
```

```html
<b>
<a href="google.com"> A Bold link</a> 
</b>

<p><a href="google.com"> A normal link</a>
```

Comment: Did not get your point? you want different different color on hover or any other point?

Comment: `b:hover a{}` and `p:hover a{}` ?

Comment: like this https://jsfiddle.net/96v6xwy7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just use different selectors. One with the `b` parent and another without.
 This would work as long as the bold link text is achieved using the `b` tag around the hyperlink.

```css
a:hover {
  color: #cccccc;
}
b > a:hover {
  color: #cccc00;
}
```

```html
<b>
<a href="google.com"> A Bold link</a> 
</b>

<p><a href="google.com"> A normal link</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please add this css:

```
b a:hover {
  color: #ff0000;
}
p a:hover {
  color: #008000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use style

```
a{ color: red; }
b a{ color: blue; }

<b>
    <a href="google.com"> A Bold link</a> 
</b>

<p><a href="google.com"> A normal link</a>
```

suggest view : csstricks   https://css-tricks.com/